# plot jpg image in R language

Tags: r, plot

I'm using R console to create `jpg` image. First I plot some image on the screen like `plot(1, 1)` then I use `dev.print(jpeg, 'test')` to create jpg file. But there's an error:

> Error in grDevices::dev.copy(device = function (filename = "Rplot%03d.jpeg",  :   invalid graphics state

I tried to solve it by closing the current image and plot again, by `dev.off()`, but after that I can't plot a new image:

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large.

Comment: Try `dev.copy(jpeg, "test.jpg")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pascal's solution in the comments works great, here's what you can do, too:

```
jpeg('test.jpg')
plot(1,1)
dev.off()
```

Comment: This command will work but I don't really know how to set the window size.. I tried `jpeg('rplot.jpg', width=10, height = 2)` but when I run `plot(1, 1)` I got this error: 
`Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`

Comment: shu, look at `?jpeg`: the height and width are to be given in pixels... hence why the plot in your comment is too small to render.

Comment: as mentioned above, the default for jpeg is height=480 and width=480. If you want bigger/smaller you can adjust from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
savePlot(test.jpeg",type="jpeg")
```

Also look for `?savePlot`

Comment: I guess the type is `"jpeg"`?
I tried `savePlot("test",type="jpeg")` but I got this:
`Error in savePlot("test", type = "jpeg") : 
  can only copy from 'X11(type="*cairo")' devices`

Comment: Sorry, yes jpeg. or you can save it to tiff as per your need.